# Gaming on an esxi vm

Tags: virtual-machine, gaming, esxi

I did some digging around by I cant find any recent discussions about this topic. 
Given adequate hardware on the vmware esxi host, is it possible to game inside of a virtual machine with low latency and reasonable graphics?  I'm not talking about skyrim on ultra, but well enough that I can bump up render distances in WoW to max.

Comment: I see two answers here, and both are correct.  Gaming on a remote VM is still an issue. Both if you do something via ESX, VNC, RDP,  etc etc. Gaming on a local server with directly attached display wit a dedicated (to the VM) graphics card on the other hand should work. Q: for the OP: Can you add which of these two you were going for to the post?

Comment: I have a great gaming rig that is more than capable of playing our games. My goal was to reload the machine as an esxi server and allocate all resources to 2 vm's, one for her, and one for me.  I have a handful of decent laptops lieing around that I was hoping to use as our clients to connect to the esxi vm's either right through vsphere or rdp so that we can game together. Unfortunately it sounds like infosec practice we'd probably be dealing with a ton of ui latency issues so I have moved on to saving up for a new build, and she'll get the hand-me-down. ;)

Comment: Ok. I guess in theory it is still possible to game with two people on two different VMs. Both connected to a VM with a dedicated graphics card. I practise this seems hard to do. I got a desktop behind me which is intended to become an ESXi server with a dedicated graphics card (and unrelated a dedecated 10Gbit NIC) to a VM. It is one of the reasons I am reading though posts tagged [esxi] :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't found anything online about it because it's not intended for video game rendering. Some stride has been made in recent years to help with graphics acceleration within VMs. However, what you can virtualize, even with outstanding hardware can't come close to a standard PC with a decent graphics card in it in terms of video/game rendering potential.

You have to consider the fact too that the data being pumped out of a graphics card goes straight to the monitor at an extreamly high rate. If I'm not mistaken, it's in the 4gbps+ range. You're trying to force that kind of information through a Ethernet cable and also include all the overhead that comes with virtualization.

Bottom line, it's not going to work any better than a PC with a basic graphics card.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That was the general direction I figured I'd get.  I was hoping for some miraculous breakthrough in the last few years would have made it more feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would require the host hardware to support either or both of the virtualisation technologies

- Graphics virtualisation Technology (Intel GVT-d, GVT-g and GVT-s). Where Intel's integrated GPU can be either dedicatedly assigned to a virtual machine (GVT-d), shared between multiple virtual machines on a time-sharing basis while using native graphics driver (GVT-g), or shared between multiple virtual machines by using a virtual graphics driver (GVT-s)
- or IO redirection to completely allocate a PCIe graphics card to the virtual machine with either

  - AMD's I/O Virtualisation Technology, "AMD-Vi", originally called "IOMMU".
  - Intel's "Virtualisation Technology for Directed I/O" (VT-d), included in most high-end (but not all) Nehalem and newer Intel processors.

As for frame rates, I don't know, I've never had a host that supports those features, and had reasonable graphics hardware.

As for your purposes of running WoW in a virtual machine. Did you know that used to be able to, and probably still can, run multiple copies of WoW on the same machine. You may have to make a copy of the WoW folder for each instance, I'm not sure, but even if you do that would be smaller than a complete virtual machine for each.